# How to bind a node in Xtratreelist to a Xtragrid in DevExpress

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid, xtratreelist

I want to bind every node of a tree to a xtragrid like in the image attached. At this time i have a usercontrolpanel which has the Xtragrid and i am planning to show the usercontrol panel on the form each time a node is clicked and bind the node related data to the grid dynamically. Any change in the grid should update the corresponding datasource of the grid as well as that of the node. How do i go about this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the gridControl's DataSource property to the necessary value within the TreeList's [FocusedNodeChanged](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_FocusedNodeChangedtopic) event handler.  The e.Node parameter identifies the currently focused node.  Based on it, you should determine the grid's DataSource and assign it.  To determine a node value, use the node's [GetValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListNodesTreeListNode_GetValuetopic) method.